# Get the server path /home directory from php wamp windows

Tags: php, wamp, directory

I have the following hierarchy

```
c:/wamp64/www/site/folder/folder2/file.php
```

in file php I want to call to a file that is located here:

```
c:/wamp64/www/site/folder3/folder4/file2.php
```

How can I do that? `../../.` works only in some cases, if I call to the file from different locations it's not working.

I need to get always the root path, how do I get it?

Comment: ../../../folder3/folder4/file2.php

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way, First define a path `SITE_PATH` as you know which file to call which is here `folder3/folder4/file2.php`. if you are using MVC kind of framework then define `SITE_PATH` as very top most of file, so that in future if you change the base location of you project then you can change it in one variable then it will good to go.

```
<?php

define("SITE_PATH","c:/wamp64/www/site/");//defined a common path.
$fileToCall="folder3/folder4/file2.php";//file to use

require_once SITE_PATH.$fileToCall;;
```

Comment: define("SITE_PATH","c:/wamp64/www/site/");//defined a common path. 

I need it dynamic , not a string .

How do I get c:/wamp64/www/site in dynamic way

Comment: My above code  states that if you want to require `folder3/folder4/file2.php` then just put this code above you code. You will be able to require it.